# Як перекласти українською aspect value (про шрифт)?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни, типографіка

Допоможіть будь ласка перекласти словосполучення **aspect value**, у такому контексті:

> The apparent size of a font as well as its legibility can vary greatly
>   for a constant font-size value. This is especially true for scripts
>   like Latin that distinguish between upper and lowercase letters. In
>   such cases, the ratio of the height of lowercase letters to their
>   uppercase counterparts is an important factor in deciding the
>   legibility of the given font. This ratio is commonly called the **aspect
>   value** of a font.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Запитання, які стосуються перекладу, мають містити переклад своїми словами (українською), контекст (також українською), і, бажано, варіанти, які автор знайшов в Інтернеті, з поясненням, чому ці варіанти не підходять. Це запитання містить пояснення англійською, але цього може бути недостатньо.

Comment: Тобто йдеться фактично про співвідношення висот малої та великої літер (у певному шрифті) — я правильно розумію? Ні, помилився, мова про відношення висоти малих літер до розміру кегля.

Answer (score 4):

Це не зовсім правильний підхід до перекладу, оскільки ми фактично намагаємося «натягнути» переклад термінології з однієї предметної області в іншу… Але [E2U](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=aspect+ratio&dicts=all&highlight=on) пропонує такі переклади для *aspect ratio* в інших предметних областях (а *aspect ratio* використовується як [синонім](//web.archive.org/web/20170921190158///developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size-adjust#Values) до *aspect value* у вашому контексті):

- співвідношення (розмірів)
- формат (екрана, зображення, образу)
- екра́нний пара́мет(е)р
- аспе́ктне відно́шення
- видова́ пропо́рція

**Співвідношення розмірів** у цілому підходить (хоча, можливо, є занадто загальним — не вказано, яких розмірів). Але якщо один раз цей термін ввести з поясненнями (яких саме розмірів ми маємо співвідношення), то потім далі можна скорочувати його до двох слів.

<s>*Формат* — вже занадто загальне. Екранний параметр — недоречне.</s>

**Аспектне відношення** — хоч ні про що конкретне читачу це словосполучення не скаже, але в тому-то й його перевага (що є словосполучення, яке виглядає більш-менш дослівним перекладом *aspect ratio*, але в українській мові в такому вигляді майже не використовується, тому можна вважати, що «позиція не зайнята»).

<sub>Хоча обидва ці варіанти є неідеальними (перше — занадто широке, друге взагалі [в іншому значенні](//web.archive.org/web/20170315033715/https://ostec-materials.ru/tech_lib/glossary/aspektnoe-otnoshenie.php) в сусідній мові може використовуватися). Тож якщо підбереться кращий еквівалент, то про *співвідношення розмірів* і *аспектне відношення* варто забути. Але, як кажуть, у степу й хрущ м'ясо.</sub>

Comment: А де можна поставити "+" за *у степу й хрущ м'ясо*? :)

Answer (score 1):

Виходячи з цього

> All fonts have an *aspect ratio* (or *value*). Font aspect values are calculated by dividing the lowercase x-height of the font by the font size.

Пропоную `x-пропорція`.

Також можна використати просто `аспектне значення`.

Comment: Оце _x_ асоціюється з абсцисою (тобто горизонтальним розміром). Хоча якщо читати «**е**кс-пропрорція» (чи навіть писати «**е**кс- / **e**x-пропроція» — аналогічно до одиниці вимірювання _[**e**x](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#ex)_ у CSS), щоби було очевидно, що мова про (вертикальний) розмір англійської _x_, а не про _ікс_ із геометрії — то, може, спрацює. Цікаво, як українською буде _[x-height](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height)_ — _ікс-висота_?

Comment: Можна читати кирилично, різницї у планї типографії між латинською чи кириличною _х_ наче немає тут. Хоча тут є цїкавий нюанс, ми не дуже відрізняємо терміни *мала* та *рядкова лїтера*. А [ми](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) і [не тїльки](https://www.paratype.ru/E-ZINE/issue02/knowhow.htm) позначаємо це як звична мала лїтера. Тому я би це позначив як _рядкова_, що входить  у множину _малих_.

Comment: @Follower що таке рядкова літера?

Comment: @Yola наразї те саме, що і мала лїтера. Зустрічається [инколи](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AF_(%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0)). Я пропоную, щоб та позначала ту, що в межах _x-висоти_.

Comment: @Follower, я мав на увазі різницю між читанням у нас назв англійських і «латинських» літер. Геометричні координати ми називаємо _ікс_ і _ігрек_, а не _екс_ і _в(у)ай_ — тож якщо вимовляти це слово як _**екс**-пропорція_, а не _**ікс**-пропорція_ (а на письмі, можливо, навіть як _**екс**_- чи _**ex**-пропорція_ замість _**x**-пропорція_), то, можливо, виникатиме менше недоречних натяків на горизонтальність виміру.

Answer (score 0):

Просто **[значення] аспекту**. Розглянемо чому чи які є ще варіяцїї.

В наукових галузях [аспект](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82_(%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F))

- *поточний вигляд*, який може мати *[переважно передбачувальнї] зміни*. Себто якщо лїтерно перекласти — [зафіксований] **ви[гля]д**;
- *відносне положення* до чогось

Хоч слова [вигляд](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyghljad), [вид](http://sum.in.ua/s/vyd) доволї точнї до означення, але є ризик непорозуміння. Натомість вони мають право на існування в технїчнїй сфері: **[значення чи коєфіцїєнт] ви[гля]ду**. Гадаю, приблизно так і звучить анґлїйське означення, якби не було «наукової» [латиницї](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=aspect).

А [відносність](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidnosnistj)  — навпаки, доволї абстрактне означення, бо навіть у типоґрафії відношень вистачає. Але ми [знаємо](http://www.barrypearson.co.uk/articles/text/aspect_values.htm), що то відношення [висоти малої лїтери х](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-height) до розміру [черенки](http://services.ulif.org.ua/grinch/Entry/index?wordid=60527&page=1290). Таким чином можна означити **х-відносність**. Можна читати кирилично, різницї у планї типографії між латинською чи кириличною *х* немає тут.

Хоча є цїкавий нюанс, ми не дуже відрізняємо терміни *мала* та *[рядкова](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0) лїтера*. А [ми](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%BB%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0) і [не тїльки](https://www.paratype.ru/E-ZINE/issue02/knowhow.htm) позначаємо *x-heigh* як звична *мала лїтера*. Тому я би *x-height* позначив як *рядкова* (лїтера, висота), що входить у множину *[малих](http://sum.in.ua/s/malyj)* — *lowercase*. Звідси термін буде щось на штиб **рядкова відносність** чи **рядковий коєфіцїєнт**. Звісно, можне бути конфуз із словом *рядок*, але вони залежнї між собою, а відстань між рядками вже буде *[міжрядковою](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%86%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%B6)*.

---

> **СУМ-20** ¬ [Аспект](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=1746&page=78)
>
> 2. Зовнішній вигляд рослинних угруповань, що змінюється за фазою розвитку рослин протягом року. *Аспект травостою біло-зелений від квіток білої конюшини і вегетативних пагонів лисохвосту* (з наук. літ.).
> 3. *лінгв.* Вид дієслова. *Категорія виду (аспекту) дієслів — одна з найскладніших у граматиці* (з навч. літ.).

Comment: я з повагою ставлюсь до вашого специфічного написання слів, що відрізняється від класичного (чинного) правопису і орфографічних словників, хоч і не вітаю такі відхилення на SE. Утім, якщо цитуєте той же СУМ чи інші джерела, то, згідно з правилами цитування, зберігайте, будь ласка, оригінальну орфографію, а не вводьте людей в оману ще дужче.